# MapFish print image on whole page

Tags: mapfish

I need to generate map image with vectors drawn on them. I do not have access to backend. Is it possible using mapfish to generate desired image only (not image placed on page)?

When i calculate width and height of A4 (620, 877) using 75 dpi and use it as a page size in mapfish config and use the same size in openlayers i get exception:

`Error while generating PDF:Infinite table loop; row content is larger than the page (for instance because you didn't scale an image).`

Answer (score 0):

I know, the question was asked 7 years ago, but I got solution recently for those who has the same problem.

I added absoluteX and absoluteY in config.yaml (path GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/printing/config.yaml as in [documention](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/printing/index.html)). Now it looks like:

```
mainPage:
  pageSize: 650 1000 #custom page size
  rotation: true
  items:
    - !map
      absoluteX: 0
      absoluteY: 1000
      width: 650
      height: 1000
```